# Uninstall Tuxera NTFS 2014

Tags: macos, ntfs, uninstall

I tried uninstalling Tuxera NTFS 2014 but the uninstall Tuxera NTFS button is disabled. How do I uninstall it? 
[image: Here is the picture]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you enable it does the button become enabled?

Comment: Nope, I tried every possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Tuxera, if the uninstall should fail, there's an uninstall script in
`/System/Library/Filesystems/fusefs_txantfs.fs/Support/uninstall-package.sh`

Ref: [Tuxera NTFS for Mac - Online User Manual](http://tuxera.com/mac/onlinehelp/en/index.htm#page=Uninstalling_Tuxera_NTFS_for_Mac.htm)

*Edit:* If, as you claim that file does not exist [it is incredibly unlikely the *path is incorrect*, far more likely the file is simply not there ;) Then you will probably need to try installing Tuxera again, over the top of the existing version, which ought to replace all the files correctly.

Comment: The path you specified is incorrect.

Comment: The path I specified is copy/pasted directly from Tuxera's site. It is unlikely to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Open up terminal and type:

```
$ cd  /System/Library/Filesystems/fusefs_txantfs.fs/Support/
$ ./uninstall-package.sh
```

Hope this works!

Comment: The path you specified is incorrect.

Comment: See if the /System/Library/Filesystems/fusefs_txantfs.fs directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the uninstall script to Github for reference.

(Extracted from the Tuxera NTFS 2016 package)

https://gist.github.com/gvkempen/bd93261088cc878028ae361f8dc42823

Comment: Can you write more information not just a Link?

Answer (score 0):

[gvkempen](https://superuser.com/users/569969/gvkempen)'s answer actually works and should be upvoted. For those who don't know how to follow his solution. First save his script https://gist.github.com/gvkempen/bd93261088cc878028ae361f8dc42823 to a local file uninstall-package.sh. Then cd into that folder and give it privilege by `running chmod +x uninstall-package.sh`. After that run `sudo sh uninstall-package.sh`. Then Tuxera is removed!